# Recursive binary tree search isn't returning True when the node has been found

Tags: python, recursion, tree, binary-tree

myTree is a list of lists in python that represents a binary tree. For each list within the list, element 0 represents the pointer to the left child, element 1 represents the value of the node, and element 2 represents the pointer to the right child.

```
myTree = [[1,50,2],[3,27,4],[9,62,10],[5,12,6],[7,35,8],[-1,9,-1],[-1,14,-1],[-1,28,-1],[-1,41,-1],[11,59,12],[13,71,-1],[-1,52,-1],[-1,60,-1],[-1,68,-1]]


def findNode(item,comparingNode):
    #print (comparingNode)
    comparingNode = myTree[comparingNode]
    if item == comparingNode[1]:
        print(comparingNode[1])
        return True #This is where it is supposed to return True

    elif item > comparingNode[1]:
        if comparingNode[2] != -1:
            print(comparingNode[0],comparingNode[1],comparingNode[2],"comp1")
            return findNode(item,comparingNode[2])
        else:
            return False

    else:
        if comparingNode[0] != -1: 
            print(comparingNode[0],comparingNode[1],comparingNode[2],"comp2")
            findNode(item,comparingNode[0])
        else:
            return False


    #print(comparingNode[1])




if findNode(9,0) == True:
    print("found")
```

When run, It doesn't produce an error message, and the program completes. The search has clearly found node 9 because, when run, it prints out 9 at the end. However, The function doesn't return True even though the debugger says it's visited the source line (line 9).

Comment: You forgot a `return` in the `else`/`if` branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a return in the else path. This works:

```
def findNode(item,comparingNode):
    #print (comparingNode)
    comparingNode = myTree[comparingNode]
    if item == comparingNode[1]:
        print(comparingNode[1])
        return True #This is where it is supposed to return True

    elif item > comparingNode[1]:
        if comparingNode[2] != -1:
            print(comparingNode[0],comparingNode[1],comparingNode[2],"comp1")
            return findNode(item,comparingNode[2])
        else:
            return False

    else:
        if comparingNode[0] != -1: 
            print(comparingNode[0],comparingNode[1],comparingNode[2],"comp2")
            return findNode(item,comparingNode[0])
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 0):

As Willem suggested in a comment above, the line:

```
findNode(item,comparingNode[0])
```

Should be modified to:

```
return findNode(item,comparingNode[0])
```

The the output will be:

```
1 50 2 comp2
3 27 4 comp2
5 12 6 comp2
9
found
```

Answer (score 0):

You just forgot a `return`:

```
if comparingNode[0] != -1: 
    print(comparingNode[0],comparingNode[1],comparingNode[2],"comp2")
    **** findNode(item,comparingNode[0])
else:
    return False
```

Another note: you can test without doing `== True`:

```
if findNode(9,0):
    print("found")
```